# Blogspot json - load post content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://mailliw88.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?start-index=1&max-results=2&alt=json-in-script',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        var entry = data.feed.entry;
        for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {

            postTitle = entry[i].title.$t;
            postTitleLink = entry[i].title.$t.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

            items = '<div class="items"><h2><a href="#' + postTitleLink + '">' + postTitle + '</a></h2></div>';
            document.getElementById('showlists').innerHTML += items;

            postContent = entry[i].content.$t;

            content = '<div class="contentWrap"><div id="close">CLOSE</div><h1>' + postTitle + '</h1><div>' + postContent + '</div></div>';
            document.getElementById('showlists').innerHTML += content;
        }
    }
});
```

```css
h1 {margin:0}
.contentWrap {border:1px solid red;
padding:5px}
#close {color:red;text-align:right}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='showlists'>
</div>
```

How to load post content only when clicking the title?
I can use .toggle in jquery but I need to load and "unload" content, not just showing and hiding it. I hope i'm making sense.

My skill is limited to css only, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:none` to `<div class="contentWrap">` and on click of `a` tag you can show the content using `closest()` and `next()`.And on click of `close` again use `"display", "none"` to hide that content div .

**Demo Code** :

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://mailliw88.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?start-index=1&max-results=2&alt=json-in-script',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        var entry = data.feed.entry;
        for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {

            postTitle = entry[i].title.$t;
            postTitleLink = entry[i].title.$t.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

            items = '<div class="items"><h2><a href="#' + postTitleLink + '">' + postTitle + '</a></h2></div>';
            document.getElementById('showlists').innerHTML += items;

            postContent = entry[i].content.$t;
//added display none and added class = close
            content = '<div style="display:none"class="contentWrap"><div class="close">CLOSE</div><h1>' + postTitle + '</h1><div>' + postContent + '</div></div>';
            document.getElementById('showlists').innerHTML += content;
        }
    }
});
//on click of a tag show content
$(document).on("click","a",function(){
//a->closest div->next content->show
$(this).closest(".items").next(".contentWrap").css("display", "block");


})
//onclick of close -> hide again
$(document).on("click",".close",function(){
$(this).closest(".contentWrap").css("display", "none");
})
```

```css
h1 {margin:0}
.contentWrap {border:1px solid red;
padding:5px}
.close {color:red;text-align:right}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='showlists'>
</div>
```

**Update 1** :

You can assign `i` value some custom attribute and then use same `index` value to access post content.In below code snippets i have not send again request to server to load json on click of `a` instead i have use some variable to store content of `data.feed.entry` in some variable and then use this to add content .

**Demo Code** :

```js
var datas = "";
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://mailliw88.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?start-index=1&max-results=2&alt=json-in-script',
  type: 'get',
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(data) {
  //adding entry content in datas to use later
    datas = data.feed.entry;
    var entry = data.feed.entry;
    for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {

      postTitle = entry[i].title.$t;
     postTitleLink = entry[i].title.$t.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
      //passing index no i.e : " i " in custom attribute 
      items = '<div class="items"><h2><a data-val=' + i + ' href="#' + postTitleLink + '">' + postTitle + '</a></h2></div>';
      document.getElementById('showlists').innerHTML += items;
       }
  }
});
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
$(".contentWrap").remove(); //remove previous div
  var ids = $(this).attr('data-val');
  console.log(ids)
  //getting data that index position got from a tag
  postTitle = datas[ids].title.$t;
  postTitleLink = datas[ids].title.$t.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
  postContent = datas[ids].content.$t;

  content = '<div class="contentWrap"><div class="close">CLOSE</div><h1>' + postTitle + '</h1><div>' + postContent + '</div></div>';
  document.getElementById('showlists').innerHTML += content;



})
```

```css
h1 {margin:0}
.contentWrap {border:1px solid red;
padding:5px}
.close {color:red;text-align:right}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showlists"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. That was actually my first approach. Im just wondering if it is possible to load only when clicked, not load everything on page load.. When I "inspect" it before clicking it, I can still see the hidden contents.

Comment: i have some video contents, even if I close it, the video is still playing.

Comment: you can load onclick by passing `id` of that post , but how you need to unload ? when another title is clicked?

Comment: yes, coz I am placing all the items into the sidebar. thanks

Comment: check `update 1` and let me know if that works for you .

Comment: thank you so much for spending time on this. It works. by the way do u offer gigs in fiverr?